# Problem with spring web application while deployment on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I try to deploy a simple spring web application on tomcat using Eclipse IDE, but I face the following exception when trying to run the application on the server:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
```

I search and found that I have to use the absolute ordering tag right after the display name in the "web.xml" but it didn't work for me. 
I also changed the Spring JARS many times I thought the JARS my be corrupted.

I tried to clean the tomcat and the web directory but nothing worked.

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0">
   <display-name>spring_mvc_1</display-name>
   <absolute-ordering />
   <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->
   <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

PageController:

```
package com.app.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class PageController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "mainPage";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your **pom.xml** ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua, I manually include the JARS, I don't use maven, I downloaded them through the spring repo.

Comment: @Can you post a screenshot of your jar list?

Comment: @AvijitBarua
i edited the post and added the JAR list

Comment: Can you please check my answer? And of course let me know about your result!

Comment: @AvijitBarua Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: What is your tomcat version?

Comment: It is tomcat 8.5, I moved to tomcat 9 and it worked!!

Comment: Then your problem is solved ?